# Google Maps v3 - Can't get a polygon and/or rectangle to display on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been working on a .NET geocoding application that at the end displays a Google Map (using the v3 API) of an address or place. The map has a marker in the centre representing the point that is geocoded. This all works. I then wanted to display a rectangle/polygon shape overlay on the map that represents the bounds surrounding the point that was geocoded (this reflects the accuracy of the geocoding, with larger bounds representing less accuracy). (I get the co-ordinates of these bounds back from the API query).

However, I just **cannot** get a polygon or rectange to display on the map and it's driving me crazy! I've followed the instructions in the [documentation for polygons](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Polygons) but no joy. I've tried `google.maps.Polygon` and `google.maps.Rectangle`, but with no luck for either. I've also tried different lat/lngs for the bounds but it made no difference. Nothing ever shows. I must be making some fundamental mistake, but can't see any trees in these woods!

The basic code (which is generated from C#) I have looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.attachEvent) {window.attachEvent('onload', initMap);}
        else if (window.addEventListener) {window.addEventListener('load', initMap, false);}
        else {document.addEventListener('load', initMap, false);}

    function initMap() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5001524,-0.1262362);
        var myOptions = { zoom: 15, center: latlng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng, map: map, title:'Westminster, London, UK' 
        });
        var boundCoords = [
            new google.maps.LatLng(51.3493528),
            new google.maps.LatLng(-0.378358),
            new google.maps.LatLng(51.7040647),
            new google.maps.LatLng(0.1502295),
        ];
        var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: boundCoords, strokeColor: '#FF0000', strokeOpacity: 0.8, 
            strokeWeight: 3, fillColor: '#FF0000', fillOpacity: 0.35 
        });
        poly.setMap(map); 
        console.log(poly);
    }
</script>

<div id="map_canvas" style="width:640px; height:480px"></div>
```

There is a JSFiddle version [available here](http://jsfiddle.net/MWjen/1/) you can play with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new google.maps.LatLng(51.3493528),
```

You need x,y coords, for example

```
new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.75737),
```

OR

you need two markers, example:

```
var latLngBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
   marker1.getPosition(),
   marker2.getPosition()
);
rectangle.setBounds(latLngBounds);
```

Comment: Doh! Can't believe I missed that! Many thanks for pointing out the obvious (though I wonder why it didn't cause a JS error?)